# Entity with fixed size list vs entity with multiple attributes

Tags: java, oop

Let's say you're defining an entity called `SoccerTeam`, with the following rules:

- Every team has an exact number of 11 players.
- There are no substitutes.
- Every player has a shirt with a number going from 1 to 11.

What would be the proper way to define this on an entity?

1. Define a list that would always have 11 values, where each value correspond to one shirt number.
2. Define a eleven attributes, each corresponding to one shirt number.

Comment: 3. Use a more general data storage method, because I assume the requirements will change more than once before this makes it to production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it looks like there are two data models 1. SoccerTeam 2. Player. To impose validations like exact 11 players in the SoccerTeam, you can use other validations annotations just to keep the validation and the data separate. For example `@Size, @Min, @Max`

```
class SoccerTeam {
  @Size(min= 11, max = 11)
  private List<Player> players;
}

class Player {
  @Min(1)
  @Max(11)
  int shirtNumber;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This seems the best way to do it, since I'm persisting this data. Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

I would use a HashMap so that each shirt number should have one player Name. By using this, you can easily change it at any time. However, in order to limit the capacity of the HashMap, you would need to encapsulate it in an object through which you will validate the addition if the maximum capacity desired by you is reached. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You could try create something general which could be used more easily later: 
- Create an entity called Player which will hold a "int shirtNumber" and I would go with the first approach for storing data in the team ( create a list which will hold 11 values, and the values would be Player entities ).